# how to calculate distance travelled

Tags: android, location

I am developing an application in which I need to calculate the distance travelled. I am facing a problem while calculating the distance.
Here is my code:

```
 locationmanager.requestLocationUpdates(bestProvider,0,0,new Listener());

 public class Listener implements LocationListener{

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    if(location!=null) {
        if(loc1==null) {
            loc1=new Location(location);
        }

        speed=location.getSpeed()*3.6;
        loc2=new Location(location);
        dist+=loc1.distanceTo(loc2);
        loc1=loc2;
        breaktv.setText(""+dist/1000);
```

My intention is calculate the total distance travelled by car or something. But `distanceTo()` method is not working well for me.

Comment: "is not working well for me" doesn't give us much to go on.  What are you seeing?  How do you know it's not working?

Comment: What is the question and what is the input? Euclidian distance is often quite easy to compute (using square roots, squares, additions, substractions of coordinates)?

Comment: Here I requested for updates frequently.So onLocationChanged() will be called everytime when there is a change in location.I am facing problem at this point of  code while calculating the distance.I am adding distance every time here,is it correct.? loc2=new Location(location);
        dist+=loc1.distanceTo(loc2);
        loc1=loc2;
        breaktv.setText(""+dist/1000);

Answer (score 2):

Technically it should work.

I have some suggestions :

- `dist` must be `float` (if it isn't already)
- `dist += loc2.distanceTo(location)`, there is no need to create `loc1`

---

This is the code I've used

```
                if(lastLoc != null)
                {
                    ttf = (location.getTime() - lastLoc.getTime()) / 1000;
                    int R = 6371;
                    double lat1 = Math.PI / 180.0 *lastLoc.getLatitude();
                    double lon1 = Math.PI / 180.0 *lastLoc.getLongitude();
                    double lat2 = Math.PI / 180.0 *location.getLatitude();
                    double lon2 = Math.PI / 180.0 *location.getLongitude();
                    //  double dLon = Math.PI / 180.0 * (location.getLongitude() - lastLoc.getLongitude());
                    double dLat = (lat2-lat1);
                    double dLon = (lon2-lon1);
                    double a = Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) +
                    Math.cos(lat1) * Math.cos(lat2) * 
                    Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.sin(dLon/2); 
                    double c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a)); 
                    double d = R * c;
                   totalDistance += d;

                }

                lastLoc = location;
```

Comment: +1 Hello,Can you please look at this question,I have been searching for this from long long time http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7696112/gettting-different-distance-when-using-the-google-map-and-user-defined-function/8050014#8050014 ..also If you post anything there..please also do a comment on my answer so i get to know.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another **[Question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7696112/gettting-different-distance-when-using-the-google-map-and-user-defined-function/8050014#8050014)** where I have posted 2 Answers one for the User Defined function to get the distance and other to User android.Location class method to calculate it.
Hope this will help you.

When You start your jurney take the **[CurrentLocation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1513485/how-do-i-get-the-current-gps-location-programmatically-in-android)** and store it may be using **[SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html)**,
Then I think you need to Continuosly keep updating the Distance Travelled,
You just use **[OnLocationChanged](http://www.firstdroid.com/2010/04/29/android-development-using-gps-to-get-current-location-2/)** same way and Call the method above two mentioned from there to know the Current Distance Travelled.

EDIT:
here is a good example that may help you,**[Link To OpenSource Project](http://code.google.com/p/distancecalc/)**

Comment: Hii Frankenstein thank you for your reply.This is exactly what I am trying to do.I stored the previous location in loc1 object and new location in loc2,and I am trying to use both these objects in distanceTo() method and adding the result everytime.Am I going In right direction????

Comment: I dont see any problem...please see updated ans i have add one more link.