# Distance calculation from my location to destination location in android

Tags: android, location, distance

I have to made a project where i need to calculate the distance from my location to destination location and show it in a textview.Here note that this distance updated when my location change.Is it possible to make such type of project ?

[NOTE: without implementing Google map i have to make it.The destination lon ,lat is known.Just have to find my location and make the calculation]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

check the documentation on the google android dev page to see how to listen for position changes. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/obtaining-user-location.html

you can use this function to determine the distance between the current (start) point and the target point.

```
 /**
 * using WSG84
 * using the Metric system
 */
public static float getDistance(double startLati, double startLongi, double goalLati, double goalLongi){
    float[] resultArray = new float[99];
    Location.distanceBetween(startLati, startLongi, goalLati, goalLongi, resultArray);
    return resultArray[0];
}
```

Comment: you could start a new asynctask, when a new position is gained (see the link above). In the onpostexecute method you can write the distance in the textview.

Comment: but how?i am sorry .i am new in android.would you please explain it here or give me the code to display it in textview?

Comment: you create a listener (see link). in the onLocationChanged() Method you execute a new AsyncTask. This task needs to have a reference on the textview (-> findViewById()). In the doInBackground() Method of the task you calculate the distance and in the onPostExecute() Method you set the text of the textview. Maybe theres a more elegant way to archiv this, but it works :)

Comment: Please also divide result with 1000 if you want result in km , like "return resultArray[0]/1000;"

Answer (score 12):

`Location.distanceBetween` will give to straight distance between two point. If you want distance of PATH between two geographical point then you can use do this by using this class :

```
public class GetDistance {

public String GetRoutDistane(double startLat, double startLong, double endLat, double endLong)
{
  String Distance = "error";
  String Status = "error";
  try {
      Log.e("Distance Link : ", "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin="+ startLat +","+ startLong +"&destination="+ endLat +","+ endLong +"&sensor=false");
        JSONObject jsonObj = parser_Json.getJSONfromURL("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin="+ startLat +","+ startLong +"&destination="+ endLat +","+ endLong +"&sensor=false"); 
        Status = jsonObj.getString("status");
        if(Status.equalsIgnoreCase("OK"))
        {
        JSONArray routes = jsonObj.getJSONArray("routes"); 
         JSONObject zero = routes.getJSONObject(0);
         JSONArray legs = zero.getJSONArray("legs");
         JSONObject zero2 = legs.getJSONObject(0);
         JSONObject dist = zero2.getJSONObject("distance");
         Distance = dist.getString("text");
        }
        else
        {
            Distance = "Too Far";
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
return Distance;


}
```

}

This will give you distance or length of path/road between two points.

**and here is the parser_Json class which parse JSON api**

```
 public class parser_Json {

public static JSONObject getJSONfromURL(String url){

    //initialize
    InputStream is = null;
    String result = "";
    JSONObject jArray = null;

    //http post
    try{
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        is = entity.getContent();

    }catch(Exception e){
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
    }

    //convert response to string
    try{
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        result=sb.toString();
    }catch(Exception e){
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
    }

    //try parse the string to a JSON object
    try{
            jArray = new JSONObject(result);
    }catch(JSONException e){
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
    }

    return jArray;
}

 public static InputStream retrieveStream(String url) {

        DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(); 

        HttpGet getRequest = new HttpGet(url);

        try {

           HttpResponse getResponse = client.execute(getRequest);
           final int statusCode = getResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

           if (statusCode != HttpStatus.SC_OK) { 

              return null;
           }

           HttpEntity getResponseEntity = getResponse.getEntity();
           return getResponseEntity.getContent();

        } 
        catch (IOException e) {
           getRequest.abort();

        }

        return null;

     }
```

}

Answer (score 4):

I have written down 2 different answers here in **[this Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7696112/gettting-different-distance-when-using-the-google-map-and-user-defined-function/7752341#7752341)** to calculate difference between two geo-points so not copy pasting here,

Second thing also see **[this Example](http://www.firstdroid.com/2010/04/29/android-development-using-gps-to-get-current-location-2/)** the same way you need to implement `Locationlistener` to get `onLocationChanged` event.

And in that event calculate difference using above given functions and use them appropriately.

Answer (score 3):

This is fairly straightforward using `LocationServices` to determine your location and updating your `TextView` with the new distance every time an update is received.