# how to find the correct distance between two geopoints in map?

Tags: android, android-location

I need to develop app where user has to locate his car that he has parked and show distance between him and car parked.I used GPS and location services.

For distance i used **haversine** formula but the distance always shows 0 meters.

I tried a lot searching for solution in google but dint get any correct solution.

Can anyone give their suggestions?

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2741403/get-the-distance-between-two-geo-points

Comment: Read all answers of this Question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7696112/gettting-different-distance-when-using-the-google-map-and-user-defined-function/7752341#7752341

Comment: look at the question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19218081/how-to-calculate-distance-from-different-markers-in-a-map-and-then-pick-up-the-l). This has similar answer with multiple distance calculations. See the accepted answer.

Answer (score 12):

Google Docs have two methods

[image]

If you are getting lat/lon from GeoPoint then they are in microdegrees. You must multiply by 1e6.

**But i preferred to use below method. (its based on Haversine Formula)**

http://www.codecodex.com/wiki/Calculate_Distance_Between_Two_Points_on_a_Globe

```
double dist = GeoUtils.distanceKm(mylat, mylon, lat, lon);

 /**
 * Computes the distance in kilometers between two points on Earth.
 * 
 * @param lat1 Latitude of the first point
 * @param lon1 Longitude of the first point
 * @param lat2 Latitude of the second point
 * @param lon2 Longitude of the second point
 * @return Distance between the two points in kilometers.
 */

public static double distanceKm(double lat1, double lon1, double lat2, double lon2) {
    int EARTH_RADIUS_KM = 6371;
    double lat1Rad = Math.toRadians(lat1);
    double lat2Rad = Math.toRadians(lat2);
    double deltaLonRad = Math.toRadians(lon2 - lon1);

    return Math.acos(Math.sin(lat1Rad) * Math.sin(lat2Rad) + Math.cos(lat1Rad) * Math.cos(lat2Rad) * Math.cos(deltaLonRad)) * EARTH_RADIUS_KM;
}
```

At last i would like to share bonus information.

**If you are looking for driving directions, route between two locations then head to**

http://code.google.com/p/j2memaprouteprovider/

Comment: @VipulShah - I think this give straight distance between two GeoPoints, Not a Direction or Driving Distance, Right?

Comment: @user370305 Perfect!! If you need driving distance and path then see http://code.google.com/p/j2memaprouteprovider/

Comment: @vipul, but what is the distance usually being show in android applications? straight/driving?

Comment: @Archie.bpgc I think its straight...You may have the option to see driving distance

Answer (score 3):

Try using This method in *android.location* API

[distanceBetween(double startLatitude, double startLongitude, double endLatitude, double endLongitude, float[] results)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#distanceBetween%28double,%20double,%20double,%20double,%20float%5B%5D%29)

This method computes the approximate distance in meters between two locations, and optionally the initial and final bearings of the shortest path between them

**NB:** If you are getting lat/lon from GeoPoint then they are in microdegrees. You must multiply by 1E6

IF you want to calculate distace between 2 Geopoint by **Haversine formula**

```
public class DistanceCalculator {
   // earth’s radius = 6,371km
   private static final double EARTH_RADIUS = 6371 ;
   public static double distanceCalcByHaversine(GeoPoint startP, GeoPoint endP) {
      double lat1 = startP.getLatitudeE6()/1E6;
      double lat2 = endP.getLatitudeE6()/1E6;
      double lon1 = startP.getLongitudeE6()/1E6;
      double lon2 = endP.getLongitudeE6()/1E6;
      double dLat = Math.toRadians(lat2-lat1);
      double dLon = Math.toRadians(lon2-lon1);
      double a = Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) +
      Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat1)) * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat2)) *
      Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.sin(dLon/2);
      double c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a));
      return EARTH_RADIUS * c;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`distanceBetween()` method will give you straight distance between two points. Got get route distance between two points see my ansewer  [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10683554/distance-calculation-from-my-location-to-destination-location-in-android/10749705#10749705)

Answer (score 1):

android.location.Location.distanceBetween(double startLatitude, double startLongitude, double endLatitude, double endLongitude, float[] results)

Geopoints have getLongitudeE6() and getLatitudeE6() to help. Remember that those are E6 so you need to divide by 1E6.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with the harvesine formula is that it doesn't calculate the real distance. It's the distance from 2 points on a sphere. The real distance depends on the streets, or the water ways. The harvesine formula is also a bit complicated hence it is easier to ask Google-Api to give the real distance. With Googlemaps Api you need to learn the directions api.

Answer (score 0):

distanceBetween does not reffer to the real distance (the road distance) 
So i suggest to you to visit this google source code and it will dispaly you the real road distance between 2 geopoints. 
[Link](http://code.google.com/p/j2memaprouteprovider/source/browse/?r=12#svn/trunk/J2MEMapRouteAndroidEx) 
there is 2 versions one for **Android** and one for **blackberry** check it out