# How can i find distance between two GeoPoints

Tags: android, google-maps

Can i receive distance from a kml file? (Sorry for the bad language)

```
urlString.append("http://maps.google.com/maps?");
urlString.append("&saddr=");//from
urlString.append(src.getLatitudeE6()/1e6);urlString.append(","); 
urlString.append(src.getLongitudeE6()/1e6); 
urlString.append("&daddr=");//to 
urlString.append( dest.getLatitudeE6()/1e6); 
urlString.append(","); 
urlString.append( dest.getLongitudeE6()/1e6); 
urlString.append("&ie=UTF8&0&om=0&output=kml");
```

Comment: Not sure about kml file...but i have already answered on how to find distance between two GeoPoints here..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11294208/how-to-find-the-correct-distance-between-two-geopoints-in-map/11294271#11294271

Comment: @VipulShah but distance is more for example i know that distance will be no more 3-4 km but answer is 355775.4232.:(

Answer (score 0):

This might be helpful to you

```
public static Double calculateDistance(Double lat1, Double lon1, Double lat2, Double lon2) {
    Double Radius = 6371.00;
    Double dLat = toRadians(lat2 - lat1);
    Double dLon = toRadians(lon2 - lon1);
    Double a = Math.sin(dLat / 2) * Math.sin(dLat / 2)
            + Math.cos(toRadians(lat1)) * Math.cos(toRadians(lat2))
            * Math.sin(dLon / 2) * Math.sin(dLon / 2);
    Double c = 2 * Math.asin(Math.sqrt(a));
    return Radius * c;
}
```

pass source latitude and longitude and destination latitude and longtitude as parameters

Answer (score 0):

The URL you have given was working properly for few months but now suddenly it stopped working and KML file is not being downloaded,instead path is showed under google maps,i guess it is in conflict of intrests with google's policy.

Comment: try using JSON object and parse it
http://maps.google.com/maps?f=d&hl=en&saddr=vizianagaram,&daddr=vishakapatnam,&ie=UTF8&0&om=0&output=json